# Running two test classes in sequence while using gradle --parallel to run the tests

Tags: junit, gradle

We have two different test classes (each contains several test methods), they may affect each other while running in parallel and in the same jvm process. I know this sounds bad, but currently we have no easy solution to separate those two test classes.

How to specify the running order of these two test classes (to make them run in sequennce) while I still want the parallel test execution using gradle --parallel? Thanks a lot in advance.

[UPDATE]:

I have the following configurations

```
test {
// maxParallelForks=8
testLogging.showStandardStreams=true

    exclude '**/ATests.scala'
    exclude '**/BTests.scala'
}

task runATests(type: Test) {
    include '**/ATests.scala'
}

task runBTests(type: Test) {
    include '**/BTests.scala'
}
```

How can I verify that ATests and BTests are actuall run in different test JVM, from the logs, it seems have no
related information about this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't related to parallel task or test execution (which, by the way, are independent Gradle features) because Gradle runs tests in a single thread per test JVM. The problem is simply that multiple tests access the same singleton and invalidate each other's expectations of that object's initial state. Possible solutions:

- Make each affected test reset the singleton to a known state.
- Make sure that each affected test is executed by a different `Test` task (and hence runs in a different test JVM).
- Get rid of the singleton.

Comment: you are absolutely right about the problem. Since the two test classes are in the same project, how can we configure them that they run in different test tasks? could you please provide some examples? Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi Peter, could you please take at look at my further questions in the above [UPDATE]? thanks a lot

Comment: It's always guaranteed that separate test tasks use separate test JVMs. You don't have to check it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Gradle documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) tests always run in a seperate jvm process. Therefore you should have no problems when  both tests are in different projects and run in parallel.

If they are in the same project, they shouldn't run in parallel, because gradle only builds different projects in parallel, but each project itself sequential (especially the tests).

In both cases you should be fine.

If you want to parallelize your tests you can take a look at [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html), it supports parallel tests and dependencies. The conversion is usually not to time consuming, basically fix all imports (Annotation names are the same) and create and xml suite file with the tests.

Comment: thanks for your reply. In our case, the two tests are indeed in the same project. I am not familiar with the gradle internals, but from the log, we can be sure that the two tests are affecting each other. We have an companion object, which is accessible globally (we are using scala), both tests will override some fields there and thus we got some unexpected behavior.

Comment: Is maybe the execution order the problem? I never did any coding in Scala, so I think that is how far I can help you.

Comment: thanks a lot anyway. I was trying to find other solutions, for example, is there any way to specify the runtime dependencies among junit test classes, say, via some annotation? A quick google didn't find the answer.